# Application launch in WPF shell

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-shell, process.start

I have a shell application which is made in .NET. I do a `Process.Start()` to launch an application from within the shell.

Is it the best way to launch an application? I came across a weird situation where I launch `notepad.exe` from the windows folder and after launching about 30 instances of the same `exe`, I saw an extremely crash where in the display keeps blinking and after that I get logged out.

Has any one else come across the same issue?

Comment: Well .. No. but unless you are targeting your application for malicious users, why would someone try to launch 30 instances of the same applicaton?

Comment: You never know people can go nuts at times. Coming back to the topic. I tried launching the same withing windows (30 instances) and there is no issue at all.